# Attempting to load GPX and KML format files from Mail and Safari using CFBundleDocumentTypes on IPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, mime-types, kml, gpx

I've setup other binary document types (such as zip archives) and they load from Safari and Mail just fine. But the XML based formats only run the "Quick View" and show the raw XML code. Is there something else that needs to be done to support XML based formats? Here is the info.plist I am using for these types:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>  
<array>
 <dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>Icon-72.png</string>
    <string>Icon.png</string>
   </array>
   <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
   <string>GPS Exchange Format (GPX)</string>
   <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
   <string>Viewer</string>
   <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
   <string>Owner</string>
   <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
   <array>
    <string>com.topografix.gpx</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
   <array>
    <string>Icon-72.png</string>
    <string>Icon.png</string>
   </array>
   <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
   <string>Google Earth KML</string>
   <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
   <string>Viewer</string>
   <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
   <string>Owner</string>
   <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
   <array>
    <string>com.google.earth.kml</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array>
 <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
   <string>com.google.earth.kml</string>
   <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
   <string>Google Earth KML</string>
   <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
   <string>http://earth.google.com/kml/</string>
   <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
   <dict>
    <key>com.apple.ostype</key>
    <string>GKml</string>
    <key>public.filename-extension</key>
    <array>
     <string>kml</string>
    </array>
    <key>public.mime-type</key>
    <string>application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml</string>
   </dict>
   <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
   <array>
    <string>public.xml</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
   <string>com.topografix.gpx</string>
   <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
   <string>http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/</string>
   <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
   <string>GPS Exchange Format (GPX)</string>
   <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
   <dict>
    <key>public.filename-extension</key>
    <array>
     <string>gpx</string>
    </array>
    <key>public.mime-type</key>
    <string>application/gpx+xml</string>
   </dict>
   <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
   <array>
    <string>public.xml</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array>
 <key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
   <string>com.google.earth.kml</string>
   <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
   <string>Google Earth KML</string>
   <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
   <string>http://earth.google.com/kmz/</string>
   <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
   <dict>
    <key>com.apple.ostype</key>
    <string>GKml</string>
    <key>public.filename-extension</key>
    <array>
     <string>kml</string>
    </array>
    <key>public.mime-type</key>
    <string>application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml</string>
   </dict>
   <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
   <array>
    <string>public.xml</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
   <string>com.topografix.gpx</string>
   <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
   <string>GPS Exchange Format (GPX)</string>
   <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
   <string>http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/</string>
   <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
   <dict>
    <key>public.filename-extension</key>
    <array>
     <string>gpx</string>
    </array>
    <key>public.mime-type</key>
    <string>application/gpx+xml</string>
   </dict>
   <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
   <array>
    <string>public.xml</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: What were you wanting Mail and Safari to show, instead of the raw XML? What kinds of XML documents are you wanting to display in a special way? Note that XML is not a "binary document type", though your question seems to imply that it is.

Comment: Mail and Safari should show the "Open My App" screen, then the user can load the GPX into my application for display. So the files are not binary, I just want to load them and parse them in my application.

Comment: It seems that the document types like XML and plain text use "Quick Look" instead of launching my app with the document. Is there any way I can override "Quick Look" to instead launch my app?